# Rails - Alphanumeric field validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

In rails 4, I need to validate the alphanumeric field which can accept only dot(.), hyphen(-), slash(/) and space in between the characters.

Eg: `AB123-GH345` or `AB45.NH744` or `KHJ3/SD34` or `HJS23 JKA34`

I have tried with `/^[0-9]+#$/` and `/^\d+([.,]\d+)?$/` and `/^[0-9]+#$/` but it is not working as per the requirement.

Value should be accept as per the examples. Please help me to validate this field.

Comment: What is the `#` in your attempted regular expressions meant to do? That character doesn't have any special meaning in a regular expression. You haven't really given us enough information. Are the following values valid? `0`, `A`, `.`, `.- /`, `A/0`, `-NH744`, `123AB-345GH`, `AB123.GH345.LM567`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might help you:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9-\/\.\s]+$/
```

This worked for all the examples you have provided

`AB123-GH345` or `AB45.NH744` or `KHJ3/SD34` or `HJS23 JKA34`

and rejected when I inserted a character like `?` in the middle(`HJS23?JKA34`).

---

**Update**

If you don't want multiline anchors then you can use it like this:

```
/\A[A-Za-z0-9-\/\.\s]+\z/
```

You can use this [Rubular](http://rubular.com) site to validate your Regex codes.

Comment: Thank You. `/\A[A-Za-z0-9-\/\.\s]+\z/` is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

- Try this:

  ```
  /^[a-zA-Z\d\.\-\/# ]+$/
  ```

Comment: After using this I am getting an error like `ArgumentError (The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $)`

Comment: You can [set the `:multiline` option to *true*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions) to enable these `^`/`$` anchors, but I doubt you really need them.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\. /'\-]+$
```

Hope this will help